# Laplace Transform of the Product of a function and the Step Function

Tags: integral-transforms

I need to find the Laplace transform of the product of a function $f(t)$ with the Unit Heaviside Step Function $H(t-c)$, i.e., $\text{L}[H(t-c)f(t)]$.

Given that

$$\text{L}[H(t)f(t-c)] = e^{-sc}F(s)\hspace{5cm} \text{EQ. 1}$$

is a well known result, I made the substitution $y=t-c$ to get

$$\text{L}[H(t-c)f(t)] = \text{L}[H(y)f(y+c)] =\text{L}[H(y)f(y-(-c))]$$

I then made what I'm afraid is the questionable claim that

$$\text{L}[H(y)f(y-(-c))]=e^{-s(-c)}F(s)=e^{sc}F(s)$$

The reason that I feel this is questionable is because I suspect that EQ. 1 above is only valid for $c\ge0$.

Could someone comment on whether my approach is valid, and if not, what the correct Laplace transform of $H(t-c)f(t)$ actually is?

Thanks

Comment: For the bilateral Laplace transform, $\mathcal{L} \{ f(t-c) \} = e^{-s \cdot c} \cdot F(s)$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. time-shifitng). However, I assume you're using the one-sided Laplace transform (given the identity in EQ 1), so I'm not certain the above identity holds. Sorry if that doesn't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Your Eq. (1) is not true; it should be $\mathscr{L}[H(t-c)f(t-c)](s) = e^{-sc}F(s)$ instead, while
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}[H(t-c)f(t)](s)
   &= \int_0^\infty H(t-c)f(t)e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \int_c^\infty f(t)e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \int_0^\infty f(t+c)e^{-s(t+c)} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= e^{-sc}\mathscr{L}[f(t+c)](s)
\end{align}
$$
which cannot be expressed in function of $F(s)$ in general. However, alternatively, you may write from the second line :
$$
\mathscr{L}[H(t-c)f(t)](s) = F(s) - \int_0^c f(t)e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t
$$